# An error occurred during deployment plan generation. Deployment cannot continue

Tags: visual-studio, azure, windows-8.1

I had been publishing a Lightswitch app to an Azure website and a linked SQL database. Publishing quit working with the following error in Lightsswitch.

**Error 1   An exception occurred when deploying the database for the application.
An error occurred during deployment plan generation. Deployment cannot continue.    C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\LightSwitch\v4.5\Publish\v2.4\Microsoft.LightSwitch.Publish.targets   1565    10**

I recreated the application and setup a new and website and link SQL database on an Azure account and continue to get the same error.

Answer (score 0):

After being able to publish a different app to a different Azure Subscription from the same computer I started from scratch in VS and Azure (again) and was able to publish. I conclude that something was wrong with the project.