# error during deployment plan generation

Tags: deployment, sql-server-data-tools

I'm trying to use a deployment contributor to dynamically prevent the deployment of some schema's. I've resolved several errors regarding loading the component: ['AdditionalDeploymentContributors' is not a valid argument for the 'Publish' action](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38793315/additionaldeploymentcontributors-is-not-a-valid-argument-for-the-publish-act)

And it seems to load now, but during execution it still encounters an error:

```
*** An error occurred during deployment plan generation. Deployment cannot continue.
Error SQL0: Required contributor with id 'AgileSqlClub.DeploymentFilterContributor' could not be loaded.
```

So the deployment contributor fails and therefore the whole thing can't be loaded.
I've tried to find this error in the source code and just the internet, but only this one and it's about Azure:
[An error occurred during deployment plan generation. Deployment cannot continue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26091355/an-error-occurred-during-deployment-plan-generation-deployment-cannot-continue)

Filter:

```
SqlPackageFilter0=IgnoreSchema(nl)
```

Any idea's on what's going wrong?

Comment: What version of ssdt/DacFx is it? Is it from the 130 folder?

Comment: @EdElliott Yes, after installing the update from my other question, I'm using the 130 version.

Comment: cool - see the codeplex issue :)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error

> *** An error occurred during deployment plan generation. Deployment cannot continue.
>   Error SQL0: Required contributor with id
>   'AgileSqlClub.DeploymentFilterContributor' could not be loaded.

while using DAC 120 with 1.4.4.0 version of [AgileSqlClub.SqlPackageFilter (directly clone from github)](https://github.com/GoEddie/DeploymentContributorFilterer).

After several attempts, the solution for my case is to install [DacFx 17.1](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=55255) which (DAC 140) finally seems to match the version of SqlPackageFilter I'm using.